# HTML Input replace previous text

Tags: jquery, html, input, replace, overwrite

I am trying to make it so an input, with maxlength of 1 has it so, when you type again it replaces the current value. Example: 1, then type 2 it changes to 2.

Here is the code I am using to keep the text as only a number (jQuery)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
        (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: And what's the question here?

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follows Add else condition in second if condition

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function (e) {
  
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
        (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
         
             // let it happen, don't do anything           
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
      
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
       $("#txtboxToFilter").val('');
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtboxToFilter" maxlength="1">
```